# Can not Drivermanager.getConnection(...) in android app

Tags: java, android, mysql, android-studio, jdbc

I have a problem to connect on my DB from android application. The lib for connect (mysql-connector-java.5.1.41-bin) is added to project.

**Function for connect and insert to DB**

```
public void insert(String SMS_ID, String SMS_ADRESS, String SMS_TEXT, String SMS_CREATOR, String SMS_DATE) throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.14:3306/smschecker";
            Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "root"); //there it jumps to catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
            PreparedStatement st = c.prepareStatement("insert into SMS values (?,?,?,?,?)");

            st.setString(1, SMS_ID);
            st.setString(2, SMS_ADRESS);
            st.setString(3, SMS_TEXT);
            st.setString(4, SMS_CREATOR);
            st.setString(5, SMS_DATE);

            st.execute();
            st.close();
            c.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

**Screenshots from DB GUI**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZ1bv.jpg //Connection informations

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ODDPm.jpg //Users

The problem is may be between users, that the app has no permission to enter the DB, but I do not know how to add a permission for my app.

Comment: I tried it in NetBeans and everything is OK, so I can not understand why this do not work in android studio -_-

Comment: + some screen from debug http://imgur.com/a/i98vd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the screenshot that you've posted in your comments, identified the issue.

```
Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
```

You just can't be doing a Network IO on the main thread, you might have to move that to an Async task or a new thread.

Hope that this helps!

Comment: Of course, this helped me, I found this solution yesterday in the night hours, but really thank you so much for your reaction! But my question is now, that how to stop the Thread after save datas to DB? Or is better way use AsyncTask? There is some of my code how I am using the Thread : http://pastebin.com/NtdCFL8g .

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/ZHoF2 there is screen of debugger for the second thread

Comment: @fauzt, if your problem is solved by my answer then you must consider accepting as an answer!